# JERSEY: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The output stream has already been closed

Tags: jersey-2.0

I can access the data from browser using "localhost". But if I mention my system IP address the app is showing below error:

```
    SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The output stream has already been closed.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.setStreamProvider(CommittingOutputStream.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.setStreamProvider(OutboundMessageContext.java:812)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.setStreamProvider(ContainerResponse.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:645)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:395)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my AuthenticationFilter class:

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jersey.provider;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.Base64;

/**
 * This filter verify the access permissions for a user
 * based on username and passowrd provided in request
 * */
@Provider
public class AuthenticationFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
{

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic";
    private static final Response ACCESS_DENIED = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                                                        .entity("You cannot access this resource").build();
    private static final Response ACCESS_FORBIDDEN = Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
                                                        .entity("Access blocked for all users !!").build();

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        //Access allowed for all
        if( ! method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class))
        {
            //Access denied for all
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class))
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
                return;
            }

            //Get request headers
            final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();

            //Fetch authorization header
            final List<String> authorization = headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);

            //If no authorization information present; block access
            if(authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty())
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                return;
            }

            //Get encoded username and password
            final String encodedUserPassword = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");

            //Decode username and password
            String usernameAndPassword = new String(Base64.decode(encodedUserPassword.getBytes()));;

            //Split username and password tokens
            final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(usernameAndPassword, ":");
            final String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
            final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();

            //Verifying Username and password
            System.out.println(username);
            System.out.println(password);

            //Verify user access
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class))
            {
                RolesAllowed rolesAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
                Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(rolesAnnotation.value()));

                //Is user valid?
                if( ! isUserAllowed(username, password, rolesSet))
                {
                    requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private boolean isUserAllowed(final String username, final String password, final Set<String> rolesSet)
    {
        boolean isAllowed = false;

        //Step 1. Fetch password from database and match with password in argument
        //If both match then get the defined role for user from database and continue; else return isAllowed [false]
        //Access the database and do this part yourself
        //String userRole = userMgr.getUserRole(username);

        if(username.equals("howtodoinjava") && password.equals("password"))
        {
            String userRole = "ADMIN";

            //Step 2. Verify user role
            if(rolesSet.contains(userRole))
            {
                isAllowed = true;
            }
        }
        return isAllowed;
    }
}
```

This is my JerseyService class

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jersey.provider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/employees")
public class JerseyService
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Employees getAllEmployees()
    {
        Employees list = new Employees();
        list.setEmployeeList(new ArrayList<Employees>());

        list.getEmployeeList().add(new Employees(1, "Lokesh Gupta"));
        list.getEmployeeList().add(new Employees(2, "Alex Kolenchiskey"));
        list.getEmployeeList().add(new Employees(3, "David Kameron"));

        return list;
    }
}
```

This is my GsonMessageBodyHandler class:

```
package com.howtodoinjava.jersey.provider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;

import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class GsonMessageBodyHandler implements MessageBodyWriter<Object>,
        MessageBodyReader<Object> {
    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

    private Gson gson;

    //Customize the gson behavior here
    private Gson getGson() {
        if (gson == null) {
            final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
            gson = gsonBuilder.disableHtmlEscaping()
                    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                    .setPrettyPrinting()
                    .serializeNulls()
                    .create();
        }
        return gson;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            java.lang.annotation.Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) {
        InputStreamReader streamReader = null;
        try {
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(entityStream, UTF_8);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Type jsonType;
            if (type.equals(genericType)) {
                jsonType = type;
            } else {
                jsonType = genericType;
            }
            return getGson().fromJson(streamReader, jsonType);
        } finally {
            try {
                streamReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object object, Class<?> type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
            OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(entityStream, UTF_8);
        try {
            Type jsonType;
            if (type.equals(genericType)) {
                jsonType = type;
            } else {
                jsonType = genericType;
            }
            getGson().toJson(object, jsonType, writer);
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I could not identifying the issue. Please help to resolve the above error.

Comment: are you getting this error on jersey client ? where is your client code ?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the use of a static Response

```
private static final Response ACCESS_DENIED = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("You cannot access this resource").build();
```

The first time you get no error but trying to access the resource a second time trows the error you mentioned. The error has nothing to do with using localhost or the IP of the related host. So modify the code in your AuthenticationFilter like so:

```
@Provider
public class AuthenticationFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;
    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic";

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
{
    Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    //Access allowed for all
    if( ! method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class))
    {
        //Access denied for all
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class))
        {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("Access blocked for all users !!").build(););
            return;
        }

        //Get request headers
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = equestContext.getHeaders();

        //Fetch authorization header
        final List<String> authorization = headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);

        //If no authorization information present; block access
        if(authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty())
        {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("You cannot access this resource").build(););
            return;
        }

        //Get encoded username and password
        final String encodedUserPassword = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");

        //Decode username and password
        String usernameAndPassword = new String(Base64.decode(encodedUserPassword.getBytes()));;

        //Split username and password tokens
        final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(usernameAndPassword, ":");
        final String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
        final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();

        //Verifying Username and password
        System.out.println(username);
        System.out.println(password);

        //Verify user access
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(RolesAllowed.class))
        {
            RolesAllowed rolesAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
            Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(rolesAnnotation.value()));

            //Is user valid?
            if( ! isUserAllowed(username, password, rolesSet))
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("You cannot access this resource").build(););
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your authentication will work smoothly.

Comment: OP should accept this answer

Comment: @[hank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295962/hank):
Thank you for your message.
But he unfortunately doesn't have to.